# Populating Dictionary From File

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to populate a dictionary with the IDs of lines text from my input file. If the subreddit matches one of the dictionary keys, I want to add that ID to the list in the dictionary value. Here is the code I have:

```
from collections import Counter, namedtuple, defaultdict
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv

# READ LINES INTO LIST (STRIP)
output_file = open("top_ten_subreddits", "w")
with open("subreddit", "r") as file:
    subreddits = [line.rstrip("\n") for line in file]
    subreddits = Counter(subreddits)
    top_ten = subreddits.most_common(10)
    for subreddit in top_ten:
        output_file.write("{}\n".format(subreddit))
#Make dictionary: key = subreddit, values = []


top_subreddit_names, top_subreddit_values = map(list, zip(*top_ten))

#print(top_subreddit_names, top_subreddit_values)
subreddits_dict = dict.fromkeys(top_subreddit_names, [])

#populate dictionary with comment IDs
with open("subreddit", "r") as file:
    for idx, line in enumerate(file):
        if line.strip() in top_subreddit_names:
            line = line.strip()
            subreddits_dict[line].append(idx)
         
for sub in subreddits_dict.keys():
    print(len(subreddits_dict[sub]))
    print(subreddits_dict[sub][0:10])
```

However, for some reason (I think) the ID is getting appended to every list, instead of the matching list. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the output:

```
17660
[4, 5, 11, 12, 14, 15, 18, 19, 20, 21]
17660
[4, 5, 11, 12, 14, 15, 18, 19, 20, 21]
17660
[4, 5, 11, 12, 14, 15, 18, 19, 20, 21]
17660
[4, 5, 11, 12, 14, 15, 18, 19, 20, 21]
17660
[4, 5, 11, 12, 14, 15, 18, 19, 20, 21]
17660
[4, 5, 11, 12, 14, 15, 18, 19, 20, 21]
17660
[4, 5, 11, 12, 14, 15, 18, 19, 20, 21]
17660
[4, 5, 11, 12, 14, 15, 18, 19, 20, 21]
17660
[4, 5, 11, 12, 14, 15, 18, 19, 20, 21]
17660
[4, 5, 11, 12, 14, 15, 18, 19, 20, 21]
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please tag with the language you're using (Python?)

Comment: `dict.fromkeys(top_subreddit_names, [])` is using the *same* empty list as the value for each key.  `.fromkeys()` is basically not usable with a mutable value.  A `defaultdict(list)` would work better here, without needing to be initialized with all of the keys.